# Forge Viewer in BIM 360 Teams

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

First of all, I really love the work you guys have done with the integration of the Forge Viewer in BIM 360 Teams! Kudos!

To my question:
I want to configure the Forge Viewer that displays my model when I click on my specific project in Teams.
Examples: Let's say I wanted to edit some CSS, or add an extension.

My understanding is that both the Forge Viewer and BIM 360 Teams has open API and that I therefor can be able to modify as per my request?

Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want to customize the BIM 360 Team webpage directly. This is not possible.

The Viewer in BIM 360 Team is a specific implementation of the Forge Viewer. You cannot customize it (e.g. via CSS), or load extensions into it. I.e. BIM 360 Team does not currently expose any API that allows you to directly customize the BIM 360 'user interface'.

However, you can use the Autodesk Forge APIs to create your own webpage that can list the files in a user's BIM 360 Team account (Data Management API) and allow them to be displayed in your own Forge Viewer implementation, and customize the Viewer behavior as you need..

To understand how to navigate the BIM 360 Team project/folder structure, take a look at [this tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/). To list the contents of a folder, use [this API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/). Basic Viewer customization is covered in the [Viewer tutorials](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/).

If that is what you want, if you explain what specific Viewer customizations you need, then we should be able to point you to a code snippet or sample that demonstrates it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, we have actually already created our own webpage using the Forge APIs, however, there is this one specific functionality within the Forge Viewer that's implemented in BIM 360 Team that we would very much like to add to our webpage: This is the "Comment on Points" functionality. Do you happen to know if you'd be able to help us look in the right direction to achieve something like this?

Comment: This is the functionality I am referring to:
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/a360/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/Autodesk-360-New/files/GUID-C10F6F56-DEFC-4F5A-BBD0-45ED693C5B38-htm.html

Comment: The comments feature in BIM is not exposed through a public API, you would need to implement your own, it's a mix of backend API and UI customization in the viewer, so we cannot point out easily how to achieve this. You can take a look at existing examples: http://autode.sk/2yAkYz3 or demos http://autode.sk/2yz8eII but this may not fit in your stack (node.js+react)

Comment: Thanks you Philippe. One last question: I understand that the Fusion Connect API is exposed through a public API. The comments feature is implemented in the viewer within Fusion. Does this mean that we could access this backend API and UI customization through the Fusion API?

Comment: No. The Comments API is not exposed anywhere as a public API.